# Being notified when CloudFront has completed deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to get notified when CloudFront distribution has been deployed? Or more generally when the Status (and possibly State) has changed?

In principle I could create a periodic (say, 15 minutes) checker that would poll the distribution list and see whether any property has changed, but considering most of the time this doesn't really change it feels wasteful, plus it is more work (I need to remember the previous state, so the check cannot be stateless).

So a push-based (where AWS notifies me, instead of me asking) solution is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront does not provide any push notifications for distribution configuration or state changes.

Comment: ...yet. An excellent idea, though. [#AWSWishlist](https://twitter.com/sqlbot/status/979944478600462336?s=19)